# Core Grapphics - Fill Transparent color in inner path of main path

Tags: ios, objective-c, drawing, core-graphics

I have implemented a floor drawing by path co-ordinates, and also i need to fill another path in the main path and should display transparent color in the inner path. I have tried by filling transparent color, then the inner path shows color of outer path. But how can i clear the inner path created area of outer path to show background of viewController.view?

Any suggestions would be appreciable.

[Here is the screenshot with inner & outer path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KMFF8.png)

```
if([[self.arPoints objectAtIndex:iCount] objectForKey:@"CoordsOuter"])
        {
            self.levelPointInfo = [[self.arPoints objectAtIndex:iCount] objectForKey:@"CoordsLine"];
            self.levelPointInfo=[self.levelPointInfo substringFromIndex:1];
            self.levelPointInfo=[self.levelPointInfo substringToIndex:[self.levelPointInfo length]-2];
            self.arLevelPoints=[self.levelPointInfo componentsSeparatedByString:@");("];

            startPoint=CGPointMake([[[[self.arLevelPoints objectAtIndex:0] componentsSeparatedByString:@";"] objectAtIndex:1] floatValue], [[[[self.arLevelPoints objectAtIndex:0] componentsSeparatedByString:@";"] objectAtIndex:2] floatValue]);

            for(int jCount=1; jCount<[self.arLevelPoints count];++jCount)
            {
                @autoreleasepool {
                endPoint = CGPointMake([[[[self.arLevelPoints objectAtIndex:jCount] componentsSeparatedByString:@";"] objectAtIndex:1] floatValue], [[[[self.arLevelPoints objectAtIndex:jCount] componentsSeparatedByString:@";"] objectAtIndex:2] floatValue]);
                //CGContextSaveGState(context);
                CGContextSetLineCap(context, kCGLineCapSquare);
                CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [UIColor blackColor].CGColor);
                CGContextSetLineWidth(context, LINE_WIDTH);
                CGContextMoveToPoint(context,( (startPoint.x-minX)/((maxX-minX)/(self.frame.size.width-(2*paddingX)))+(paddingX) )/self.scaleValue,(self.frame.size.height - ( (startPoint.y-minY)/((maxY-minY)/(self.frame.size.height-(2*paddingY)))+(paddingY)))/self.scaleValue);
                CGContextAddLineToPoint(context,( (endPoint.x-minX)/((maxX-minX)/(self.frame.size.width-(2*paddingX)))+(paddingX))/self.scaleValue, (self.frame.size.height - ((endPoint.y-minY)/((maxY-minY)/(self.frame.size.height-(2*paddingY)))+(paddingY)))/self.scaleValue);

                CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [UIColor yellowColor].CGColor);
                CGContextStrokePath(context);
                //CGContextRestoreGState(context);
                startPoint = endPoint;
                }
            }
        }
if([[self.arPoints objectAtIndex:iCount] objectForKey:@"CoordsInner"])
        {
            self.levelPointInfo = [[self.arPoints objectAtIndex:iCount] objectForKey:@"CoordsMinus"];
            self.levelPointInfo=[self.levelPointInfo substringFromIndex:1];
            self.levelPointInfo=[self.levelPointInfo substringToIndex:[self.levelPointInfo length]-2];
            self.arLevelPoints=[self.levelPointInfo componentsSeparatedByString:@");("];

            CGPoint firstPoint;

            for(int jCount=0; jCount<[self.arLevelPoints count];++jCount)
            {
```

Comment: can you plz add some codes